# Why is hotmail mail server providing an invalid certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, smtp

It seems that `hotmail.com` mail server sitting at `hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com` is using a TLS certificate issued to `mail.protection.outlook.com`.

Both the mail server hostname and TLS certificate common name belong to the same subdomain: `protection.outlook.com`

I'm trying to understand what's happening. Am I expected to ignore this kind of name mismatch?

This report seems to point out that there's something wrong:

[image: hotmail.com TLS report]

**Edit 2018-08-04**

Report link: https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/hotmail.com

Comment: looks to me like the server is using  SNI(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). what does the report state the problem as?

Comment: Report: https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com

Comment: @JOW Looking up [MX records for hotmail.com](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3ahotmail.com&run=toolpage) I get only `hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com`, and it seems this mail server doesn't have a valid certificate for this hostname, which makes me believe SNI is not being used here. Mayabe I'm missing a step.

Comment: They've had invalid ssl certificates for years. As I work in custom smtp software, they are a big headache.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's currently fixed (2020-01-11), **Certificate chain** is valid:

> mail.protection.outlook.com
>  128 days remaining / 2048 bit
>    / sha256WithRSAEncryption
>
> ---
>
> GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
>  2062 days
>   remaining / 2048 bit / sha256WithRSAEncryption
>
> ---
>
> GlobalSign Root CA (Certificate is self-signed.)
>  2939 days
>   remaining / 2048 bit / sha1WithRSAEncryption

Report:

- https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com

Answer (score -1):

> It seems that hotmail.com mail server sitting at hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com

How often do you send messages to (mailbox)@hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com?

Where did you get hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com from?

The certificate needs to match the MX record for the domain. When I check:

```
 $ nslookup
 > set type=MX
 > outlook.com
 Server:         127.0.1.1
 Address:        127.0.1.1#53

 Non-authoritative answer:
 outlook.com     mail exchanger = 5 outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.
```

Unfortunately Thomas left off the part of the screen shot which explains *why* the certificate presented there is valid - it is because one of the subject alternate names is *.olc.protection.outlook.com which also matches the address you cited.

[image]

Comment: Back then I was developing a [custom Mail Submission Agent](https://github.com/TCGV/ModernMail) and when executing a STARTTLS command against hotmail.com servers (after resolving the domain MX records) the application was failing to validate the provided certificate. Today I remembered about it and decided to check it again, and it was fixed!